# What does the "Dice" package look like?

Tags: voltage-regulator, packages

Looking at a [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/9911.pdf) of an inverting regulator, I found something peculiar:

[image: Ordering information with strange Pin-Package]

I've never heard of a Pin-Package called "Dice" before, and it doesn't even specify the pin-count. On the [package information site](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/packaging/index.mvp?a=0&f=) of the manufacturer, this package isn't mentioned either.

What does "Dice" mean in this context and why would I want to use it?

Comment: [Dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wafer_dicing) means there is no package at all. Unless you run a big plant which has equipment to [put bare IC directly on the PCB](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/what-is-this-black-blob-on-pcb/), you don't want this.

Comment: [Dice in photos](http://zeptobars.com/en/)

Comment: Related: [What is a "DIE" package?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/56651/8159)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange naming convention for loose chips, i.e. dies from the silicon wafer with no package.

You want to use it if you are assembling your own custom IC with this device built into it. Flip-chip straight on the PCB comes to mind as well, but the die has to be made for it in the first place.

Comment: "Dice" is the plural of "die". Also, "flip-chip" is often WLCSP.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. Is that an BE vs AE language difference? I've only heard read dies? From Wikipedia: "There are three commonly used plural forms: dice, dies, and die." Guess I learned something today.

Comment: FWIW, in my experience "dice" is the accepted plural of the throwable cubes, but I've only ever seen "dies" in the context of integrated electronics.

Comment: I have seen and heard "dice" several times in the US in Silicon Valley.

Comment: @mkeith Seems like a BE/AE language thing then!

Comment: I should mention that I have heard "die" and "known good die" (or KGD) many, many times, because I have had dealings with them. Also sometimes we just say COB (chip on board). Even though we are talking about the die. So most of the time, it is something other than "dice." But I have heard it.